# Finding final velocity when initial velocity, distance travelled and acceleration are known?

Tags: calculus

I've been struggling with this, I need to find the final velocity of a car after it travels a certain distance when I know it's initial velocity and acceleration are known. Any help?

Comment: Hint: The theorem to apply here is quite fundamental

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered the basic Kinematic equations?

Let:

- $V_f$ denote the (unknown) final velocity of the car.
- $V_0$ denote the (known) initial velocity of the car.
- $a$ denote the (known) acceleration of the car.
- $d$ denote the certain distance.

You can now proceed multiple ways, but i'll just recommend using the Kinematic equation $$V_f^2=V_0^2+2\times a\times d$$ Simply plug in the knowns and it should be very straightforward.

*Note:* This is the simple case, where the acceleration is constant and we consider only one dimension, which is what I assume you are looking for?

**An Example:** Say you are given that the car has initial velocity of $V_0=5$ $m/s$, and a constant acceleration of $a=2$ $m/s^2$. You want the final velocity $V_f$ of the car after it travels $d=4$ meters. Using the above Kinematic equation , you have:
$$V_f^2=5^2+2\times2 \times 4$$
so $V_f^2=25+16=41$.
Take the square root of both sides and you get $V_f \approx 6.403$ m/s.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way forward.

Motion under constant acceleration in one dimension boils down to these equations:

$$x(t) = x(0) + v(0)t + at^2/2$$
$$v(t) = v(0) + at$$

Here, $x(t)$ is the displacement as a function of time $t$, $v(t)$ is the velocity as a function of time, and $a$ is the constant acceleration.  Additionally, $x(0), v(0)$ can be interpreted as your initial displacement and initial velocity.

(To get these two equations, one would start with $dv/dt = a$ and integrate twice with respect to $t$.)

Solve the second equation for $t$, and substitute in the first to eliminate $t$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand your answer, could you give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: I'll add some more explanation.  It was more of a nudge in the right direction.  Do you understand how to solve $v(t) = v(0) + at$ for $t$?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try looking at the problem this way:

$\int_a^b{A(t)}=V(b) - V(a)$; where $a$=initial time, $b$=final time

This shows that a definite integral of acceleration is the difference in final velocity from initial velocity.  If you are given the velocity and acceleration as functions of $t$, this approach is probably your best bet. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The general solution for the distance traveled by an object while speed varies between $v_1$ and $v_2$ with *variable* acceleration is

$$  x = \int \limits_{v_1}^{v_2} \frac{v}{a} \,{\rm d}v $$

In your case the acceleration is constant and the distance is given

$$ x = \frac{v_2^2-v_1^2}{2 a} $$

which is solved for $v_2$.

<sub>Note also that $t =\int \frac{1}{a} \,{\rm d}v$, $t =\int \frac{1}{v} \,{\rm d}x$ and $\frac{1}{2} (v_2^2-v_1^2) = \int a \,{\rm d}x$</sub>